# AWS Elastic MapReduce Streaming. Use data from nested folders as input

Tags: hadoop-streaming, elastic-map-reduce

I have data located in structure s3n://bucket/{date}/{file}.gz with > 100 folders. How to setup streaming job and use all of them as input?
Specifying s3n://bucket/ didn't help since nodes are folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify s3n://bucket/*/ as input and it should work fine.